# Android Tablet orientation change handling

Tags: android

I am showing a popup on certain activity, When the rotation got changed then the pop will be gone. Currently we are targeting the application for Api level 11. When I used the following it is working fine in simulator but not working on device

```
<activity android:name=".TwitterActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

When I have used the following statement in my manifest then it is working fine in both simulator and device.

```
 <activity android:name=".TwitterActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screensize" />
```

But we are targeting the application for Api level 11. In Api level 11 there is no "screensize"(It is from api level 13). Can any one suggest how to solve this in Api 11.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: we are targeting the application for Api level 11. In Api level 11 there is no "screensize"(It is from api level 13)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use a support library to have the features of api 13 in api 11. You need to download it, You can refer this link..
http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Answer (score 0):

first a comment: you shouldn't use `android:configChanges` to deal with rotation problems. I know it "solves" for most people, but developers should try to proper deal with the rotation.

but to directly answer your question, you just have to change the API level on your android project. Keep the manifest at 11, as you're currently targeting, but change the project properties build target to 13 or newer.